# LINQ: building a query to query multiple options

Tags: linq, entity-framework, dynamic

I'm building a dynamic query using the following approach with help of the Dynamic LINQ file (dynamic.cs):

```
    Dim qs As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Object))

    qs.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)("Price >= @", 10))
    qs.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)("Price <= @", 50))
    qs.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)("GoLive=  @", False))
    qs.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)("Format = @", "DVD"))
    qs.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)("Format = @", "BLR"))

    Dim products = From p In data.Products
                   Select p

    For Each q In qs
        products = products.Where(q.Key, q.Value)
    Next
    Dim results = products.ToList
```

This works you'd expect but see how I'm looking for both 'DVD' and 'BLR' as in the 'Format' field?
This queries for BOTH options, not either.

Is there any way using the above method of query building to somehow query either option or would it be just best to combine the 'Format' field like so:

```
    qs.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)("Format = @ OR Format = ", both options here))
```

Comment: you might take a look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/231706/Dynamic-query-with-Linq

Comment: Thanks but PredicateBuilder doesn't allow for String based expressions which I need.

Comment: How do you string base expression look like "in real environment" ? A Property, an operator and a value, or all concatenated ?

Comment: Field, operator and value as all separate properties. I concat them together depending on the operator.